# Problem while scheduling local notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

When I schedule local notification on my phone(android version - 7) the app is crashed and when I schedule same for android version - 8 or above it works perfectly In flutter

minSdkVersion 21
compileSdkVersion 33
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion

flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.4

Comment: Could you please post what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error instead app is crashes.